# Basic HTML Help Please

Tags: html

I'm starting a website and I'm coding using a MacBook Pro. The saving of the files has been something new to me but basically I opened TextEdit and when Saving the files I put them with the file extension .html instead of the file extension .txt. I have five files labelled homepage, about, services, portfolio, and contact, in that order, respectively.

Now, my homepage opens up easily. It's really simple, and I'm confused where I'm messing up. The file `homepage.html` shows a simple header  and an unordered list that will serve as a navigation bar once I get onto the CSS part of the website. When I pull up the about page it only shows the header, correctly, and one of the dots of the unordered list followed by ZERO information.

I'm thinking it's how the files we're saved? But that wouldn't make sense because the homepage was saved the exact same way, in the same format, and it pulls up. The code is essentially the same with a different header and title. That's the only differences between the five webpages.

Anyways, the code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<title>Designs by Dante - About Me</title>

<body>

<h2>About Me</h2>

<ul id =“navigation”>
<li><a href="www.designsByDante.com/homepage.html”>Home</a></li>
<li><a href=“www.designsByDante.com/about.html”>About</a></li>
<li><a href=“www.designsByDante.com/services.html”>Services</a></li>
<li><a href=“www.designsByDante.com/portfolio.html”>Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href=“www.designsByDante.com/contact.html”>Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Simple, right?

Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For future reference cursing in your questions is frowned upon ;)

Comment: I will refrain from cursing in my questions from here on out. Thank you for reminding me. I curse a lot just in my speech. I don't mean disrespect behind it. But I will adhere to the boards rules as I love this forum and the people behind it. You all are extremely quick to respond and, most of all, HELPFUL! I really do appreciate this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes as `"` not `”`.
the reason for that is the `/` on the URL
www.designsByDante.com**/**contact.html

if the URL was with no / it would work fine.

[Check the correct code](http://jsfiddle.net/chankeypathak/x3ctP/)

If you'd have used some HTML code editor or IDE then you would have easily noticed the wrong syntax highlighting.

Comment: The "html://" part was needed before the URL. Any chance you explain why that is? Is it just necessary for the page to read that it's a webpage?

Second, what did you mean by using double quotes a different way? How do I make it straight up and down and not curved? It seems like it does that automatically.

Lastly, would you have a HTML code editor or IDE that you recommend or is free? You're right. When I coded in Dreamweaver it automatically would tell me when I'm wrong. Same went for Visual Basic. I figured I'd take a more traditional approach and ditch Dreamweaver and learn the basics.

Comment: It's not `html://`, it's `http://`. It's safe to use `http://` before any URL else it's left to browser on how he interprets it, so to be safe always use `http://`. Secondly always use the correct double quotes which is `"`. It's the standard. Thirdly you can use notepad++, it's lightweight and free. You can also try [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3). I mostly use jsFiddle and Notepad++.

Comment: You're right. I used http not html it was just a mistype. I'll start using notepad++ thanks for the suggestion. and the help.

Answer (score 2):

you should try this

```
               <html>
                  <title>Designs by Dante - About Me</title>
               <body>

               <h2>About Me</h2>

                <ul id ="navigation">
                   <li><a href="http://www.designsByDante.com/homepage.html">Home</a>                       </li>
                   <li><a href="http://www.designsByDante.com/about.html">About</a></li>
                   <li><a href="http://www.designsByDante.com/services.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.designsByDante.com/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.designsByDante.com/contact.html">Contact</a>                 </li>
                   </ul>

            </body>

            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong quotes - use " instead of “ . Perhaps your text editor replaced them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use protocol with the links - "http://" or "https://". 
Also, as others said, use the double quotes - ".

Answer (score -3):

Hey may this is what it should look like

```
<title>Designs by Dante - About Me</title>

<body>

<h2>About Me</h2>

<ul id =“navigation”>
<li><a href='www.designsByDante.com/homepage.html'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='www.designsByDante.com/about.html'>About</a></li>
<li><a href='www.designsByDante.com/services.html'>Services</a></li>
<li><a href='www.designsByDante.com/portfolio.html'>Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href='www.designsByDante.com/contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</body>

</html>
```